# How to change the direction of flow in type-c

Tags: linux-kernel, usb

I have an ASUS TUF laptop running windows 11 and an Acer Aspire laptop running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. My ASUS charger is missing so I'm figuring out ways to charge the laptop. I wanted to know how can I control the flow of charge if I connect both the laptops using the Type-C port.

Both the laptops have a type-c port and ig both support pd. But when I connect them both using type-c, nothing happens. I connected the windows laptop to my android phone using type-c then I got the option to charge the laptop in my android phone.

**What I tried:**

I tried running : `ls /sys/class | grep typec` but it didn't return anything so now I'm not sure if its because of hardware or the kernel. So please let me know if there is something by which I can atleast check if my device support change of flow and if it does, then how do i change it.

Comment: Laptops supporting power input by USB-PD are fairly common but I don't know of any laptop that supports power output by USB-PD.  USB-C ports on any computer today is likely limited to 7.5 watts (5V@1.5A) or 15 watts (5V@3A), and this power flow is negotiated by USB-BC or USB 3.x rather than USB-PD.  I've seen laptops that will charge (slowly) from 5 volts but this could be a rarity.  I'd suggest checking the power output and power input capabilities for the laptops before taking this too far, it might not work even if the direction of power flow is controlled.